# How to check if jQuery Validation Engine is attached to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I want to be able to determine not only if the [jQuery Validation Engine](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#actions/hideall) plugin is loaded, but that it is being used on a certain form. What's the quickest way to do this?

I know I could [hide all prompts](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#actions/hideall), [validate](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#actions/validate) (returns either true/false), and then [show all prompts](http://posabsolute.github.com/jQuery-Validation-Engine/#actions/showprompt-prompttext-type-promptposition-showarrow) again, but that's not nice (especially because it might have been intended to show all prompts to begin with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the jQuery Validation Engine loaded?

```
if (jQuery().validationEngine)
```

Is it being used on a certain form?

```
if ($('#formID').data('jqv'))
```